# Kivy Disable Hardware

Tags: python, kivy

When creating a Kivy application, I run into the problem that `ProbeSysfs` automatically matches certain devices it expects me to be able to use. For example:

```
[INFO     ][ProbeSysfs    ]  device match: /dev/input/event6
[INFO     ][MTD           ]  Read event from </dev/input/event6>
...
```

Is there a way to use `Config` to turn it off?

I tried `Config.set('input', 'select_all', '0')`, but that doesn't seem to accomplish anything.

Reason for this: I get odd behavior such as just moving my mouse and buttons are being pressed and `TextInput` content is being highlighted, without actual pressing of buttons.

Comment: Have you any idea what device is erroneously matching? I haven't seen people actually have an issue with this before.

Comment: Not even sure how to begin on that kind of question - all I know is that when I move the mouse around the screen, it begins to highlight and press buttons randomly. Not sure what devices or events would occur to cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your touch pad is being detected both as a mouse and as a multi touch interface.

In kivy config.ini should be in your ~/.kivy/config.ini you have two detected sources (mouse and [probesysfs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.input.providers.probesysfs.html#)).

Depending on what your needs are use either one of them.

From your description it seems you just need to comment out `probesysfs`

To do this in code just do::

```
os.environ['KCFG_INPUT_%(NAME)S'] = ''
```

[Where](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/environment.html)::

```
KCFG  - > Kivy Config
INPUT - > Section
%(NAME)S - > Value
```

[Detailed Explanation on how to control Kivy Environment](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/environment.html)::

```
You need to do this setting before anything else in your main.py
```